# Failed Audit on First Questions Queue

Tags: support, review-audits

I failed this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29990341). Here's the [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277000/error-sending-archive-to-app-store-connect).

The question asks about a strange warning message.

At the bottom of the question it says:

> Edit: Looks like Apple has fixed this as my archives are uploading without that strange warning

When I'm reviewing, I see no votes, comments, or answers, so with the last remark, it looks like a "Cannot reproduce," so I voted to close, and I failed the audit.

I don't think this is a good audit question, but I've been wrong before. Should I have handled this differently?

Comment: No, it's not a good audit question, and the question is problematic itself. Because it was a bug in a tool, not a programming question. Feel free to close it.

Comment: Ok. Will this audit count against me?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Yes, but a single audit failure every so often doesn't matter, it's only when you've made several mistakes that it matters.